# PHP ReadFile Outputs an Indent?

Tags: php, html, readfile

I'm using some PHP code to import a text file into a HTML document. The reason is because I'm having the page refresh every so often, so the text is always new. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

</head>

<body>

    <xmp>
    <?php

        $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
        $file = "..\\chat logs\\$date.txt";
        readfile($file);

    ?>
    </xmp>

</body>

</html>
```

The $date.txt file has no special spacing. No indents. The problem is the first line always has this output:

```
        [ 00:57:45 ] : <Overlord> Enemy spotted
[ 01:00:51 ] : <ShadowLordGamin> HI 
[ 01:00:58 ] : <ShadowLordGamin> just got the game today :D
[ 01:06:42 ] : <Brazdnt> D:
```

Is there any way to remove that initial indentation? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It probably depends on the HTML/CSS you use, but don't show.

Comment: Well, I added the html then. Hope it is clear what may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `<xmp>` is deprecated and badly supported. You should use `<pre>` instead and escape the text using `htmlspecialchars()` (which requires you to read the text with `file_get_contents()` instead of `readfile()`).

(EDIT: It's not only deprecated, it's also dangerous, because it opens your site for Cross-Site Scripting exploits.)

To your problem: `<xmp>` (and `<pre>`) display all characters literally between the opening and closing tags, including any spaces you use for formatting the code. You need to make sure the are no spaces between the html opening tag and the `<?php` opening tag:

```
<pre><?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
    $file = "..\\chat logs\\$date.txt";
    echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file));
?></pre>
```